# Track preprocessor's replacements

Tags: c++, preprocessor

In my C++ project, I have a header with a line like this:

```
enum { OK, ERROR_1, ERROR_2 };
```

When compiling with GCC (v 9.4.0), I get

```
error: expected identifier before '(' token
```

Examining the preprocessor output gives

```
enum { 
# 53 "/path/to/file.h" 3 4
     (0)
# 53 "/path/to/file.h"
        , ERROR_1, ERROR_2 };
```

I searched my project for a macro that would define `OK` and replace it with `(0)` but to no avail. So my question is how can I track where this `(0)` comes from? I read the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html) on preprocessor output, but haven't found anything that would aid me in my problem.

Comment: Figuring out problems like this used to be an absolute time-waster, but compilers have gotten much, much better over time. Recommendation: Throw the code at a more recent compiler and see if it will give you better diagnostics. You don't have to use the newer compiler for the actual project, just use it to get the improved diagnostics.

Comment: The definition is probably coming from some system include file that you're not paying any attention to.

Comment: You might be able to eliminate the problem with `#undef OK` just before that line.

Comment: Try defining the macro `OK` yourself. Then when the compiler reports the multiple definition error it usually tells where the first one was defined.

Comment: A carefully constructed `grep` usually solves these kinds of Scooby-Doo mysteries.

Comment: Example : Here is GCC 10  **and** GCC 4.9 pointing right at where the define came from in this admittedly trivial case https://godbolt.org/z/qr5xMxqT8  . Since 4.9 can give you this information, consider adding the build instruction and the output error messages so we can help you interpret them

Comment: Fork. You're using GCC 9.4, not 4.9. Come on, brain. Jeeeeze. Read the numbers in the right order. Same recommendation stands though. The compiler should be telling you where the original is, it might just be hard to pick out of the diagnostic crawl.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this does it! 
/usr/include/curses.h:371: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   371 | #define OK        (0)
Could you please convert your comment into an answer so that I accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example `-E -fdirectives-only` as options to GCC. It will give you a preprocessor output with all `#include`s resolved and including file/line markers, but with the macro definitions still in place and unexpanded.

Then simply search for `#define OK` in the output and search upwards for a `# N` marker where `N` is an integer. The marker will refer to the file/line from where the definition originates.

(By the way, you are looking on the wrong page of documentation. For the possible command line options affecting the preprocessor see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html.)